# external script file (alert)

Tags: javascript, html, external

I have a html problem with external java script.

Java-script

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
```

Alert doesn't work. Could you please help? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Have you coupled the external javascript file correctly with your html? `<script src="path/script.js" type="text/javascript" />

Comment: If Mario's comment didn't help, please post the HTML-snippet of `myForm`. This code seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your javascript path was incorrect check your  src="file_path/your_file.js

try this

```
    <html>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <body>
    <form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

external js (test.js)

```
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    }
```